# React react-router-dom question how to have "/" treated as a string in the url route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to have URLs be unique identifiers in my route. This requires "/" be treated as strings somehow. I was wondering if someone knew how this could be done?

Here is an example of the code.

```
<Routes>
   <Route path=":url" element={<UrlPage />}} />
</Routes>
```

So lets say we go to [www.website.com/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask](http://www.website.com/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

I would want "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask" to be the URL. How do I get the entire "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask" to be treated as string by react router.

Update:
The following will treat everything a string but if a URL has a ? everything to the right will be ignored.

```
<Routes>
   <Route path="*" element={<UrlPage />}} />
</Routes>
```

Comment: The entire URL ***is*** a string, so your question doesn't make a lot of sense. If passing any additional URLs/paths in the URL path doesn't work for you, then pass the url as a query string parameter, something like `"www.website.com/external?url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"`.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a good idea in general - not only will you have to set this up serverside to deploy this somewhere, but URLs containing `/` shouldn't be used as subdirectories.

If you *really* need to, I would URL-encode the address first like this:

```
www.website.com/https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2Fask
```

Comment: No can do in this case. We need users to be easily able to type in www.website.com/url they want. We can not do any encoding.

The workout for subdirectories is that this is our last router out of all of our routers. So all other cases are considered first. If this URL is not found serverside we return 404.